# Как задать определенную последовательность свойств в массиве объектов?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив объектов следующего формата:

```
var arr = [
  { key: 'title', value['front end', 'back end'] }
  { key: 'location', value['london'] }
  { key: 'type', value['full-time'] }
]
```

Каким образом можно установить определенную очередность следования свойств в таком массиве? Например, чтобы `type` был первым, `title` - вторым, а `location` - третьим.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var arr = [
  { key: 'title', value: ['front end', 'back end'] }, 
  { key: 'location', value: ['london'] }, 
  { key: 'type', value: ['full-time'] }
];

var keyOrder = ['type', 'title', 'location'];

arr.sort((a,b) => keyOrder.indexOf(a.key) - keyOrder.indexOf(b.key));

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Назначить по индексу:

```
var arr = [];
arr[0] = {type: "bla bla"}
arr[2] = {location: "blabla"}
```

arr выглядит так:

```
[{type: "bla bla"}, empty, {location: "blabla"}]
```